# Specifying transformation method used by gdaltransform

Tags: gdal

I'm using the gdaltransform application and it's all working fine for a NAD27 to WGS84 transform:

```
echo -e "303772.84 3118058.28\n" | gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:26716 -t_srs EPSG:32616

303775.096935672 3118259.00103859 0
```

However, when I look at the EPSG database I see there are number of different variants of the [NAD27 to WGS84 transform](https://epsg.org/search/by-name?&searchedTerms=NAD27%2BWGS84#transformation) with either different transformation methods or parameters (e.g. [EPSG:15851](https://epsg.org/transformation_15851/NAD27-to-WGS-84-79.html) vs. [EPSG:1176](https://epsg.org/transformation_1176/NAD27-to-WGS-84-7.html) )

My question is based on the assumption that I should expect a subtly different result depending on the variant I used (please, please educate me if this assumption is false) -  so how can I specify the transformation variant to use?

The documentation seems to hint at using the -ct flag but my attempt to do this failed:

```
echo -e "303772.84 3118058.28\n" | gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:26716 -t_srs EPSG:32616 -ct  urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::15851
```

> ERROR 1: PROJ: hgridshift: Invalid latitude
>
> transformation failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transformation https://epsg.org/transformation_15851/NAD27-to-WGS-84-79.html is between NAD27 and WGS 84 and the input must be in NAD27 degrees like in this example:

```
gdaltransform -ct  urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::15851
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
44 -106
43.9999782177784 -106.000572917552 0
```

With a projinfo tool you can get the complete pipelines or WKT2 definitions for the whole coordinate transformation.

```
projinfo -s EPSG:26716 -t EPSG:32616 --spatial-test intersects
Candidate operations found: 35
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:
...
PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +inv +proj=utm +zone=16 +ellps=clrk66
  +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=us_noaa_conus.tif
  +step +proj=utm +zone=16 +ellps=WGS84

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of UTM zone 16N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (79) + UTM zone 16N",
...
```

Gdaltransform usage with the Proj pipeline:

```
gdaltransform -ct  "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=utm +zone=16 +ellps=clrk66 +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=us_noaa_conus.tif +step +proj=utm +zone=16 +ellps=WGS84"
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
303772.84 3118058.28
303775.096935672 3118259.00103859 0
```

The transformation EPSG:1179 NAD27 to WGS 84 (7) does not appear in any of 35 candidate operations because it is valid in Alaska and your CRS EPSG:26716 is valid in "North America - 90°W to 84°W and NAD27 by country" and those two validity areas do not intersect.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, very helpful. A little more awkward than I was expecting or would like but such is life ;-)